# Object id error in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, error-handling, system-tables

I want to know the object referenced as an `associatedObjectId` in a deadlock graph, so I ran the below query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(1234560112364076)
```

I get the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks more like a `hobt_id` than an `object_id`. Try:

```
SELECT [schema] = s.name, [table] = o.name, [index] = i.name
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
ON i.index_id = p.index_id
AND i.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
WHERE p.hobt_id = 1234560112364076
GROUP BY s.name, o.name, i.name;
```

Also, I recommend opening the .xdl in [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer), which should present you with friendly object names instead of long, indecipherable ids. I explain the deadlock analysis functionality [here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/new-deadlock-visualizations-in-sql-sentry-and-plan-explorer).

Comment: Bingo ! you are great it gives me the index now